# Reflected Brownian Motion

Tags: probability

Let $Y(t)$ be a reflected brownian motion. Also let $G(t)$ be a process which keeps count of the number of times $Y(t)$ has hit the value $0$. How do I approach to get distribution of $Y(t)$?

Comment: Difficult to do since $G(t)=+\infty$ almost surely for every $t\gt0$.

Answer (score 1):

In fact you don't need the reflected brownian motion to "keep count" of the zeros. I put quotes because this is a rather complex question, since the zero set of the BM is not so gentle, in fact it is closed but without isolated points (think of it!). Anyways the question is answered with the [Local Time Theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_time_%28mathematics%29%20/%20Local%20Time%20theory). The local time at zero $L_t$ is an increasing random process for which its derivative $dL_t$ defines a random measure concentrated on the set of zeroes of the BM. See also [Tanaka's Formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tanaka%27s_formula).